# unable to update the fields in model Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to edit user details of a specific user when admin logins its going to edit page but when I press the update button it's not updating not showing any error message. (correct me please if I am wrong).
This is my edit.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}edit details{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% if emp %}
<form method="POST" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" ">  
    {% csrf_token %}  
<div class="container">  
<br>  
<div class="form-group row">  
<label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label"></label>  
<div class="col-sm-4">  
<h3>Update Details</h3>  
 </div>  
</div>  
<div class="form-group row">  
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Employee User:</label>  
<div class="col-sm-4">  
    <input type="text"  id="id_user" required maxlength="20" value="{{ 
  emp.user }}"/>  
  </div>  
</div>  
<div class="form-group row">  
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Employee first_name:</label>  
<div class="col-sm-4">  
    <input type="search"  id="id_first_name" required maxlength="100" 
  value="{{ emp.first_name }}" />  
  </div>  
</div>
<div class="form-group row">  
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Employee last_name:</label>  
<div class="col-sm-4">  
    <input type="text"  id="id_last_name" required maxlength="100" value="{{ 
   emp.last_name }}" />
 </div>  
</div>    
<div class="form-group row">  
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Employee Email:</label>  
<div class="col-sm-4">  
    <input type="email"  id="id_email" required maxlength="254" value="{{ 
  emp.email }}" />  
 </div>  
</div>  
<div class="form-group row">  
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Employee Gender:</label>  
<div class="col-sm-4">  
    <input type="text"  id="id_gender" required maxlength="15" value="{{ 
  emp.gender }}" />  
 </div>  
</div>
<div class="form-group row">  
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Employee Age:</label>  
<div class="col-sm-4">  
    <input type="text"  id="id_age" required maxlength="100" value="{{ 
  emp.age }}" />
 </div>  
</div>
<div class="form-group row">  
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Employee salary:</label>  
<div class="col-sm-4">  
    <input type="text" name="ename" id="id_salary" required maxlength="100" 
  value="{{ emp.salary }}" />
 </div>  
</div>    
<div class="form-group row">  
<label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label"></label>  
<div class="col-sm-4">  
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>  
  </div>  
</div>  
</div>  
</form>
{% endif %}  
{% endblock %}
```

This is my profile.html page

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
 {% if user.is_superuser %}
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm">  
  <thead class="thead-dark">  
  <tr>  
    <th>Employee User</th>  
    <th>Employee first_name</th>  
    <th>Employee last_name</th>  
    <th>Employee Email</th>
    <th>Employee Gender</th>
    <th>Employee Age</th>
    <th>Employee Salary</th>        
    <th>Actions</th>  
 </tr>  
 </thead>  
<tbody>  
 {% for employee in employees %}  
 <tr>  
    <td>{{ employee.user }}</td>  
    <td>{{ employee.first_name }}</td>  
    <td>{{ employee.last_name }}</td>  
    <td>{{ employee.email }}</td>
    <td>{{ employee.gender }}</td>
    <td>{{ employee.age }}</td>
    <td>{{ employee.salary }}</td>  
    <td>  
        <a href="{% url 'edit' employee.id %}"><span class="glyphicon 
        glyphicon-pencil" >Edit</span></a>  
        <a href="/delete/{{ employee.id }}">Delete</a>  
    </td>  
 </tr>  
{% endfor %}  
</tbody>  
</table>  
<br>  
<br>  
<center><a href="{% url 'signup' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Add New 
  Record</a></center>
 {% else %}
<p>username : {{ user }}</p>
<p>firstname : {{ user.first_name }}</p>
<p>lastname : {{ user.last_name }}</p>
<p>{{user.employee.age}}</p>
<p>
<a href="{% url 'edit_profile' %}">Edit details</a>
</p>
<p>
<a href="{% url 'change_password' %}">Change password</a>
</p>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

This is view.py of edit method

```
def edit(request, emp_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        emp = employee.objects.get(pk=emp_id)
        form = EmployeForm(request.POST or None, instance=emp)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, ('Item has been edited'))
            return HttpResponseRedirect('view_profile')
    else:
        emp = employee.objects.get(pk=emp_id)
    return render(request, 'edit.html', {'emp': emp})

def view_profile(request):
    employees = employee.objects.all()    
    args= {'user':request.user,'employees':employees}
    return render(request,'profile.html',args)
```

This is my model page

```
class employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=(('M','Male'), 
     ('F','Female')),blank=True)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    salary = models.CharField(blank = True,max_length=50

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

Please, any advice on how to troubleshoot or any documentation I can read.

Comment: what will show print `form.is_valid()` and `form.errors` before `if` statement in view?

Comment: same as before i placed form.errors before form.is_valid() and also after the it statement no error response @Satevg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the form properly. Forms are not only for validation, they are also responsible for rendering the error messages. You want to change your view to pass the form to the template:

```
def edit(request, emp_id):
    emp = employee.objects.get(pk=emp_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmployeForm(request.POST, instance=emp)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, ('Item has been edited'))
            # this one is probably not going to work
            # as expected - you may want to check the
            # doc for the `redirect` shortcut instead
            return HttpResponseRedirect('view_profile')
    else:
        form = EmployeForm(instance=emp)

    return render(request, 'edit.html', {'emp': emp, 'form':form})
```

Then in your template instead of manually writing the whole form markup, [use the form for rendering](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html)  so you have the validation errors correctly displayed.